# How to Remove Curly Braces in HashMap Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap, spinner, curly-braces

I have ArrayAdapter for spinnner and i want to add item to this spinner. My code like below

```
public void parser()
{
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> valuesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i = 0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){
        SoapObject dersListesi = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < dersListesi.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            Object objectNames = dersListesi.getProperty(j);

            SoapObject ders_kodu = (SoapObject)objectNames;
            SoapObject ders_adi = (SoapObject)objectNames;
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String dersKodu = ders_kodu.getProperty("dersKodu").toString();

            String dersAdi =  ders_adi.getProperty("dersAdi").toString();

            map.put( dersKodu,dersAdi);

            valuesList.add(map);
            System.out.println( "map"+map);
            System.out.println(dersAdi);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> ad =
                new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valuesList);
        ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDersKodu = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.derscombo);
        spinnerDersKodu.setAdapter(ad);


    }

}
```

This code work correctly but my spinner's output like this:

{BIM101=Computer Programming}

How I can remove these curly braces and = ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the your ArrayAdapter to hold string instance. You do not need an ArrayList of HashMap, if the purpose it's just printing the key and the value of the HashMap

```
final ArrayList<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int i = 0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){
        SoapObject dersListesi = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < dersListesi.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            Object objectNames = dersListesi.getProperty(j);
            SoapObject ders_kodu = (SoapObject)objectNames;
            SoapObject ders_adi = (SoapObject)objectNames;          
            String dersKodu = ders_kodu.getProperty("dersKodu").toString();
            String dersAdi =  ders_adi.getProperty("dersAdi").toString();
            valuesList.add(dersKodu+ " " + dersAdi);             
        }
  ArrayAdapter<String> ad =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valuesList);
```